# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of - LoginActivity

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I am developing an android application which requires user to login, when i run the LoginActivity it gives me a json parser error, i think my php code is fine but i need another pair of eyes to help me find the bug in my code, thanks

Login Activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

Button btnLogin;
EditText inputMobile;
EditText inputCountry;

private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static String KEY_COUNTRY = "country";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    inputMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    inputCountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.country);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if ((!inputMobile.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    && (!inputCountry.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                NetAsync(view);
            } else if ((!inputMobile.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Mobile field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if ((!!inputCountry.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Country field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Mobile and Country field are empty",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working.
 **/

private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog nDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection
     * by trying Google.
     **/
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th) {

        if (th == true) {
            nDialog.dismiss();
            new ProcessLogin().execute();
        } else {
            nDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error in Network Connection",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Async Task to get and send data to My Sql database through JSON respone.
 **/
private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    String mobile, country;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        inputMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
        inputCountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.country);

        mobile = inputMobile.getText().toString();
        country = inputCountry.getText().toString();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(mobile, country);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading User Space");
                    pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                            getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                    /**
                     * Clear all previous data in SQlite database.
                     **/
                    UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                    logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME),
                            json_user.getString(KEY_MOBILE),
                            json_user.getString(KEY_COUNTRY),
                            json_user.getString(KEY_UID),
                            json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));

                    /**
                     * If JSON array details are stored in SQlite it
                     * launches the User Panel.
                     **/
                    Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MainActivity.class);
                    upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    startActivity(upanel);
                    /**
                     * Close Login Screen
                     **/
                    finish();
                } else {

                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Incorrect mobile/country",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void NetAsync(View view) {
    new NetCheck().execute();
}
```

}
PHP code

```
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
// Get tag
$tag = $_POST['tag'];

// Include Database handler
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();
// response Array
$response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

// check for tag type
if ($tag == 'login') {
    // Request type is check Login
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];

    // check for user
    $user = $db->getUserByMobileAndCountry($mobile, $country);
    if ($user != false) {
        // user found
        // echo json with success = 1
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["mobile"] = $user["mobile"];
        $response["user"]["country"] = $user["country"];
        $response["user"]["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user not found
        // echo json with error = 1
        $response["error"] = 1;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
  }

  } else {
echo "Calendar API";
}
```

**JSONPaser**

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

Stack trace

```
11-11 06:13:15.086: E/JSON Parser(28899): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input       at character 0 of 
11-11 06:13:15.096: D/AndroidRuntime(28899): Shutting down VM
11-11 06:13:15.096: W/dalvikvm(28899): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception   (group=0x418a0da0)
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899): Process: com.calendarapp, PID: 28899
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899):    at   com.calendarapp.LoginActivity$ProcessLogin.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:172)
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899):    at com.calendarapp.LoginActivity$ProcessLogin.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:1)
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
11-11 06:13:15.106: E/AndroidRuntime(28899):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you please post LoginActivity code ?

Comment: try to read output of this line `Log.e("JSON", json);` in your jsonparser class wheather it's json format ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana you can view the login activity now